# how to specify location of virtualenv?

Tags: python, deployment, virtualenv, web-deployment, virtualenvwrapper

When I create new virtualenv using virtualenvwrapper:

```
mkvirtualenv ENV
```

then directory containing `site-packages` and stuff is created under:

```
~/.virtualenv/ENV
```

Now if my home directory is shared across many machines (via nfs) it will be overwritten. Is there any way to specify there new ENV should live?

Comment: I'm confused. What version of virtualenv is this?  The default for `virtualenv ENV` is to create the `ENV` directory in your current directory (if it's not given as an absolute path).  Now if you have virtualenvwrapper its `mkvirtualenv` will create virtualenvs under `~/.virtualenv` but that's different.

Comment: Yes, I'm using mkvirtualenv command

Comment: You should probably clarify that then, since `mkvirtualenv` is a wrapper for the normal `virtualenv` command and does some things differently.

Comment: please edit the question. you mentioned virtualenvwrapper in tag, but not in question

Comment: @rafee - done, sorry for delay and confusion.

Answer (score 4):

With virtualenvwrapper you can specify where to store your envs using the `WORKON_HOME` environment variable.  If you want just a specific virtualenv to be created in a different location you can run:

```
WORKON_HOME=/path/to/envs mkvirtualenv ENVNAME
```

But you should be aware that none of the other virtualenvwrapper commands will work with that env unless you also set the alternate `WORKON_HOME` first.  I don't prefer to keep any virtualenvs directly in my home directory either, as some of them can be quite large, so I just set `export WORKON_HOME` to an alternate directory in my login scripts.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `WORKON_HOME` environment variable, which controls where new virtualenvs are created. e.g.

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/tmp/vetest
mkvirtualenv cltest
ls ~/tmp/vetest/cltest
>>> bin  include  lib  local
```

See [docs](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html) here.